# Append to bootstrap table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, bootstrap-4

I found a few other posts that seem to address this using jquery, but I would like to use javascript only.
I would like to create a table using bootstrap but can't seem to figure out how to append new data to the table. 
It is creating the header, but then just dumping the items I want as rows below the table header.

html

```
<div id = specificFailureCountTable-js></div>
```

js

```
let filterText = 'machines';
let tableData = document.getElementById("specificFailureCountTable-js"); 
let data = [["machineA",15],["machineB",54],["machineC",26]];

//set header of table
tableData.innerHTML = `
<table class="table table-striped" id = "myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">${filterText}</th>
      <th scope="col">Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  `;
  //create//append rows
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    tableData.innerHTML = tableData.innerHTML +
    `<tr>
      <th scope="row">${i}</th>
      <td>${data[i][0]}</td>
      <td>${data[i][1]}</td>
    </tr>`
}
//close off table
tableData.innerHTML = tableData.innerHTML +
  `</tbody>
  </table>`
  ;
```

Comment: You need to create single string and after the loop assign to the innerHTML otherwise you will have broken DOM structure. You can check what you've got as DOM output if you inspect the DOM using dev tools (in Chrome right click -> context menu -> inspect element or F12).

Comment: If I create single string within `for` loop it want's to create as many tables as there are `data.[i]` objects. That's why I figured I had to break it up into multiple strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use variable that will define your table append to that variable and at the end when it would be ready assign to to `tableData.innerHTML`, otherwise you will have broken DOM (not sure what the output would be but it maybe different depending on browser):

```
let filterText = 'machines';
let tableData = document.getElementById("specificFailureCountTable-js"); 
let data = [["machineA",15],["machineB",54],["machineC",26]];

//set header of table
let table = `
<table class="table table-striped" id = "myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">${filterText}</th>
      <th scope="col">Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  `;
  //create//append rows
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    table = table +
    `<tr>
      <th scope="row">${i}</th>
      <td>${data[i][0]}</td>
      <td>${data[i][1]}</td>
    </tr>`
}
//close off table
table = table +
  `</tbody>
  </table>`
  ;

tableData.innerHTML = table;
```

And one side note: you can use `table += 'xxx'` as shortcut for `table = table + 'xxx'`